# Creating new table vs adding new field

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

I am having following data :

## **Fabric Cost**

```
time     |   No fabric|BangloreSilk|Chanderi|.... <- fabric types
--------------------------------------------
01/15    |         40 |         25 |...
02/15    |         45 |         30 |...
.....    |        ... |        ... |...
```

## **Dyeing Cost**

```
time     |   No fabric|BangloreSilk|Chanderi|.... <- fabric types
--------------------------------------------
01/15    |         40 |         25 |...
02/15    |         45 |         30 |...
.....    |        ... |        ... |...
```

**And here list of fabric types will be same for both the data.**
Now to add this data I created following tables :

**fabric_type**

```
id                  int
fabric_type_name    varchar
```

And then I have two approaches .

## **Approach 1 :**

**fabric_cost**

```
id                  int
fabric_type_id      int (foreign key to fabric_type)
cost                int
```

**deying_cost**

```
id                  int
fabric_type_id      int (foreign key to fabric_type)
cost                int
```

## **Approach 2 :**

**fabric_overall_cost**

```
id                  int
fabric_type_id      int (foreign key to fabric_type)
cost                int
fabric_or_dyeing    bit (to represent 0 for fabric cost and 1 for dyeing cost)
```

Now the question is which approach will be better??

Comment: How likely are you to want to compute aggregates or perform comparisons across costs where the fabric/dyeing distinction between costs doesn't exist? Or another way to put it is - are dyeing cost and fabric cost the same "type" of thing? If so, that data belongs in *one* column in *one* table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your requirements. Are there other columns that are unique only for the `fabric_cost` table? Are there other columns that are unique only for the `dyeing_cost` table? Meaning will your 2 tables grow independently?
If yes, approach 1 is better. Otherwise, approach 2 is better because you won't need to do CRUD on 2 separate tables (for easier maintenance). 
Another approach would be:

```
id                  int
fabric_type_id      int (foreign key to fabric_type)
fabric_cost         float/double/decimal
dyeing_cost         float/double/decimal
```

This third approach is if you always have both costs. You might not want to use `int` for cost. Again, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: No, columns will be same for both the data

Comment: Ok, so you could go with your second approach or this third approach. For your second approach, you might want a separate table to note the bit you are using, so that other people know what the bit values represent. Also, you will have 2 separate rows if you go with your second approach. When you delete/read the cost for the fabric row, do you have to delete/read the corresponding dyeing row? Or are they independent? If they are not independent, I suggest the third approach.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create another table - `cost_subjects`

**cost_subjects**

```
id                  byte
subject             varchar
```

**costs**

```
id                  int
fabric_type_id      int (foreign key to fabric_type)
cost                int
cost_subject        byte (foreign key to cost_subjects table)
```

And then you can extend the table with more subjects to include in costs of fabric

Comment: But I will not have to add more cost_subjects. If I will create a new table for this, It will be remain unchanged for all time.

Comment: ok than @Linx suggestion should work, but its not as flexible. On the other hand, you will have half of the lines in db table, than you would have with my sollution :)